# Slot Machine Win Hits

Tags: combinatorics

I'm implementing slot machine for fun and not so far I found [one](http://www.slot-design.com/simulator.html)(with [PAR sheets](http://www.slot-design.com/simulator/Stat_Bug_A_Boom.xls)) which I tried to use as reference. There are couple of things which are not clear.

As example I will take only SHIRT and WILD symbols(distribution values on the reels):

```
  Symbol   R1   R2   R3   R4   R5  
 -------- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
  SHIRT     7    6    3    5    2  
  WILD      1    1    1    2    1  
  total    44   44   44   44   23
```

And Win Hits table:

```
      Combo        Win Hits     
 ---------------- ---------- -- 
  3 SHIRT            107226     
  3 SHIRT + WILD      82547     
  4 SHIRT             12600     
  4 SHIRT + WILD      18620     
  5 SHIRT              1260     
  5 SHIRT + WILD       3438
```

It's pretty clear how *5 SHIRT* was calculated(it's just multiplication of distribution values: 7*6*5*2).

Regarding to *Combo* without WILD I guessed it must be calculated as:

$$
3SHIRT =c_{s}^{1}\cdot c_{s}^{2}\cdot c_{s}^{3}\cdot (t_{4} -c_{s}^{4} )\cdot ( t_{5} - c_{s}^{5})=7\cdot 6\cdot 3( 44-5)( 23-2)=103194\\
4SHIRT =c_{s}^{1}\cdot c_{s}^{2}\cdot c_{s}^{3}\cdot c_{s}^{4} \cdot ( t_{5} - c_{s}^{5})=7\cdot 6\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot ( 23-2)=13230\\
$$

But seems I wrong, because I got values which are not equal to values from the table. So, I have a couple questions:

- What's wrong with my formula?
- How *Win Hits* with WILD are calculated?

Could anyone give me a tip or point me to appropriate books/resources/articles/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce any of their calculations except the 5 SHIRTs that you did.  If 4 SHIRT means you get four wheels coming up shirts and one coming up something besides SHIRT and WILD, it should be $7*6*3*5*(23-3)+7*6*3*(44-7)*2+7*6*(44-4)*5*2+7*(44-7)*3*5*2+(44-8)*6*3*5*2=52974$  You choose which wheel will be other than SHIRT or WILD, then multiply the possibilities like you did for five SHIRTS, then add over the wheels that can be other. To do 3 SHIRT on the assumption that it means three wheels come up shirts and the others are something besides SHIRT and WILD, you have ten choices for the three wheels that will show shirts. Your computation is close for the number of ways to get the three SHIRTS on the first three wheels, though the last two terms should be $(44-7)(23-3)$.  There are nine more possibilities, which are calculated the same way.  The total will be far larger than $107226$.  As their PAR sheets do not have computations I can't guess where their numbers come from.  If 5 SHIRT + WILD means every wheel is either a SHIRT or WILD, there should be $8*7*7*4*3=4704$.  If you subtract the ones with all SHIRTS, that leaves $3444$, not far from their $3438$, but not exact.

Answer (score 0):

Found partial solution for cases without WILD.

#### 4 SHIRT

We need to exclude all symbols on the last reel which give *win* combinations. My mistake was, that I took into account only SHIRT symbols, but not WILD. In other words combination looks like SSSSX where X is any symbol except SHIRT and WILD. So correct formula is

$$
4SHIRT =c_{s}^{1}\cdot c_{s}^{2}\cdot c_{s}^{3}\cdot c_{s}^{4} \cdot ( t_{5} - \sum  c_{s}^{k})=7\cdot 6\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot ( 23-2-1)= 12600
$$

Where $ c_{s}^{k} $ is distribution value of the symbols which have to be excluded(in our case this is SHIRT - 2 and WILD - 1).

#### 3 SHIRT

Let's consider following combination SSSXY. X as described earlier must be any symbol except SHIRT and WILD, but Y can be any symbol, because for the line of the slot machine this symbol is not taken into account at all. So with all said:
$$
3SHIRT =c_{s}^{1}\cdot c_{s}^{2}\cdot c_{s}^{3}\cdot (t_{4} - \sum c_{s}^{k} )\cdot t_{5} =7\cdot 6\cdot 3 \cdot ( 44-5-2) \cdot 23= 107226
$$

#### 2 SYMBOLS

The logic from above works for two symbols if any:
$$
2SHIRT =c_{s}^{1}\cdot c_{s}^{2}\cdot (t_{3} - \sum c_{s}^{k} )\cdot t_{4} \cdot t_{5} 
$$